# GHC package cannot be found

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a `.hs` file which imports the following module

```
import Control.Monad.State
```

this module is located in `mtl` package.

but the compiler cannot find this module or any other modules in the `mtl` package. I did check available packages using `ghc-pkg list` and I see it is already installed and exposed. it is shown in the following database:

```
/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/8.0.1-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-8.0.1/package.conf.d
```

I did try reinstalling but it warns that other packages will be broken.

I also tried `ghc-pkg recache` but it didn't help.

It seems that I cannot import any modules from any packages from `ghci`. I am running OS X El Capitan.

Comment: try setting things up in a cabal sandbox instead, this lets you have different versions of libraries installed on a per-project basis, saving you from the horrors of cabal hell, as it's affectionately known (FYI: this shows up in pretty much every language, it's not just a haskell problem)

Comment: I will research into cabal sand box. so this is pretty normal for cabal ?

Comment: @bheklilr the only package that I can import is the base package. I thought may be this can help you help me !

Comment: yeah, basically what's happened is you've gotten yourself into a place where the libraries you have installed have conflicting dependencies. Since there are conflicts, things break. These days everyone uses either cabal sandboxes or stack to mitigate this problem. Again, every language from python to C# to Haskell has this problem at some point, and all have introduced a similar solution of sandboxing, virtual environments, or whatever.

Comment: after you initialize a sandbox you need to install packages into it. By default it comes with only the standard library called base. Just cabal install mtl

Comment: and what is this error ?
"Failed to load interface for ‘Control.Monad.State’"

Comment: @bheklilr and 2 more questions. shouldn't running ghc-pkg check show if there is problem? out of curosity how can I make sure that cabal is not working as it should. and second which one is better cabal-sandboxing or stack?